# How to stop Chrome DevTools from wrapping last CSS element?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, element

When I click in a CSS definition in Google Chrome DevTools, Chrome always wraps the last Element to a new line.
For example:

```
div a.blogLink h2
```

If I click on this line in the style definition window of Chrome DevTools, Chrome will select the whole line and wrap h2 to a new line like this:

```
div a.blogLink

h2
```

Is there any way to avoid Chrome doing this?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot example of this as I cannot reproduce this based on my understanding. See: http://i.imgur.com/fqnuFWU.png

Comment: @Gideon. just added a picture

Answer (score 0):

Simply make that panel wider if you don't want it to do this.

As an example, here on Stack Overflow there's an element under `.topbar` with a class of `.topbar-wrapper`, with a small panel, this gets wrapped onto a new line:

[image]

We can make the panel wider by clicking on the left border (visible in the image above) and dragging:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't works for me. It only wraps the element to a new line, when you select or click on the definition. (as you can see in my picture above)
I can make the panel as wide as I want, it keeps doing it.